# How can you control a Windows XP\2003 taskbar size via the registry?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, windows-registry

all the googling I've done only shows me how to lock or unlock it, how to hide it, or how to control the grouping setting. What I'm looking for specifically is, when you make the task bar one or two or three levels deep, or even zero levels which isn't the same as hiding it, where is that stored in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

> zero levels which isn't the same as
>   hiding it

Not answering your queston with a 'magic' registry hack, but if your aim is to get Windows entirely without a taskbar, use the **[Taskbar Eliminator](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator)**

[image]

[image]

*Taskbar Eliminator is freeware and portable (no installation required), works with any version of Windows.*